# Keep only the selection in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have polygon of trees, this polygon variates with the area of the branch of trees.

I would like to select by a classic hand/polygon selection an area on my canvas, but instead of selecting the whole polygon I need it to keep only what's inside the selection.

As you can see below (on cadastral parcels just to illustrate): I select with a polygon

[image]
But my result is out of that polygon.

[image]

I would need to only keep the part of the polygon I selected to later calculate the area of my selection.

I would like :

- different step to do it
- OR a macro to do it
- OR python code to add in a qgis Plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating a selection, draw a polygon on a new layer (Menu layer / Create layer). Than you can use `Menu Vector / Geoprocessing / Intersection`  and set both layers as input.

*This is the result: Blue: original polygons, orange: selection, red: result after intersection:*
[image]

Comment: So easy, I didn't think of it ! I would need to do a Plugin about this, so I make a create polygon function then it activate an intersection then it calculate my area. Should work, thank you !